# Port Forwarding Works from internet not within same network

Tags: port, portforwarding, forwarding

I just obtained static IP from ISP and configured port forwarding on my Sercomm AOT-4221SR Router

While accessing **outside network** it **works properly** and shows webpage of my server however when i connect my machine to same network within LAN and visit website or static IP it shows router page i.e 192.168.0.1 (with original website URL which i entered in browser)

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is NAT reflection.

It would not work, as most routers, including the Sercomm one does not have NAT reflection feature.

I was in the same boat as you.

What I did:
Let us assume you have 3 devices from which you want to forward ports. After adding the rules in the router, with LAN IPs `192.168.0.A`, `192.168.0.B`, `192.168.0.C`
and your static IP is `W.X.Y.Z`.

Go to `duckdns.org` and create a free account.

create 3 entries

`somethingdevice1.duckdns.org` --> `W.X.Y.Z`

`somethingdevice2.duckdns.org` --> `W.X.Y.Z`

`somethingdevice2.duckdns.org` --> `W.X.Y.Z`

Now create static DNS entries as follows (I am using AdGuard instance inside a HASS instance which I am using as DNS, I created DNS rewrite rules there)

`somethingdevice1.duckdns.org` --> `192.168.0.A`

`somethingdevice2.duckdns.org` --> `192.168.0.B`

`somethingdevice3.duckdns.org` --> `192.168.0.C`

Now use these URLs to access your devices withing or outside your local network.

Answer (score 0):

192.168.0.1 this is a private IP and shouldn't be used. I am guessing that you received a public IP from ISP. Use your public IP and add port forward rules for  that IP to your web server IP

X.X.X.X:80 ------------> 192.168.0.x:80

X.X.X.X:443 ------------> 192.168.0.x:443 for HTTPS

X.X.X.X is your public IP and 192.168.0.x is the ip of machine where you are running webserver.

And point your domain name to that public IP. You can add entries in /etc/hosts for testing purposes

Comment: I configured static IP which is allotted by ISP to me. I can access websites from remote internet connections and port forwarding to services 80 443 and other works perfectly. But when i connect to same network and access URL hosted on same network it wont woks. It looks like its a NAT hairpinning issue any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: I dont think your router supports hairpinning! You can setup a local dns for the same!